# Serve media files with S3 backend and user permissions

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-s3

I'm surprised, but I couldn't find anybody with the exact same requirements in Google, so here I go. I'm designing a Django project, and I know that sensitive documents will be uploaded by the users, so I need to introduce some kind of permission control mechanism (thinking about using JWT at the moment).

To make my project stateless from an operational point of view (planning to run it in containers), I'd like to store my user-uploaded files in a distributed object storage system (S3/minio).

This is where I'm getting lost. I know that in a "regular" Django production environment, the user-uploaded media files tend to go to the `./media` folder, and the webserver serves it directly from there, without any kind of authentication. To me, this is risky and unacceptable, because shared direct links can be sniffed/leaked, and unauthorized people can get access to sensitive documents.

**Wrapping it up**:

- What's the accepted practice to store/serve user-uploaded contents
  in/from S3/minio?
- How do I control access to these files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you got your search queries wrong, cause you didn't know what to look for, which is a Django [Storage engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-file-storage/):

> If you need to provide custom file storage – a common example is storing files on some remote system – you can do so by defining a custom storage class.

Of course, this has already [been done for you](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> django-storages is a collection of custom storage backends for Django.
>
> - *Amazon S3*
> - Apache Libcloud
> - Azure Storage
> - Digital Ocean
> - DropBox
> - FTP
> - Google Cloud Storage
>   SFTP

Comment: I've read through these docs, but they don't really answer my question. I had partial success at implementing these. I can now upload a file to an S3 storage thorough the admin panel, but I couldn't find any documentation or writing on the concept of serving these files back to the user. The bucket is obviously private, so there has to be an API to get the file back from S3.
Could you point me to the right documentation or to a repository where this is already implemented, maybe? I just can't get the hang of it.

Comment: You just use `{{MEDIA_URL}}`, like any other [file upload](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/files/). Those storage engines merely replace the default `FileSystemStorage`.